# How do i specify Visual Studio test runner in tfs build script

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, msbuild, microsoft-fakes

I have used Microsoft shims in my project for writing unit tests. These tests run fine on my local machine, however when build on server the tests fail as the ms test runner does not support shims. After searching alot i found that i have to specify vs test runner to run test but it can be specified only in default template. Is there any way to specify the test runner in build script file.
I am using TFS 2013 on TFS server with upgrade template.

Comment: Is there some reason you are still using the legacy upgrade templat and not the modern .xaml templates?

Comment: it is a legacy project and we have some custom assemblies in our process

Comment: I would move to upgrade it to the default template from 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The Upgrade template was provided only for backward compatibility for folks that has serious customization investment in 2005/2008 builds. I would not expect new functionality to work in legacy builds without serious rework and effort.

I would suggest that there will likely be less effort in moving your build to the modern build templates and gain access to new features effortlessly.